# Caliburn.Micro and custom dependency properties not working

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am using the Caliburn.Micro framework for building my application. I am trying to create a custom chart control derived from the WPF toolkit chart, which needs to have 2 custom dependency properties added to it.

For some reason, Caliburn.Micro is not binding correctly to the DP's that I created, but is working fine for existing ones. Is there something that I need to do for CM to recognize these additional properties?

(In my example, the binding `Title="{Binding ChartSeriesType}"` works correctly. The `ChartData` and `ChartType` are not being updated.)

SampleChart.xaml.cs

```
public partial class SampleChart : Chart
{
    public ChartSeriesType ChartType
    {
        get { return (ChartSeriesType)GetValue(ChartTypeProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ChartTypeProperty, value);
            dataChaged();
        }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ChartType.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChartTypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ChartType", typeof(ChartSeriesType), typeof(SampleChart), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


    public AgilityTableBase ChartData
    {
        get { return (AgilityTableBase)GetValue(ChartDataProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ChartDataProperty, value);
            dataChaged();
        }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ChartData.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChartDataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ChartData", typeof(AgilityTableBase), typeof(SampleChart), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    private void dataChaged()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("data changed");
    } 
}
```

SampleChartView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Agility.Presentation.ReportViewing.SampleChartView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Agility.Presentation.ReportViewing"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="300" mc:Ignorable="d">
<local:SampleChart Title="{Binding ChartSeriesType}" ChartData="{Binding ReportTable}" ChartType="{Binding ChartSeriesType}" />
```

SampleChartViewModel.cs:

```
public class SampleChartViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private ChartSeriesType _chartType;
    private SampleTableBase _reportTable;

    public SampleChartViewModel(SampleTableBase reportTable)
    {
        _reportTable = reportTable;
    }

    public SampleTableBase ReportTable
    {
        get { return _reportTable; }
        set
        {
            _reportTable = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ReportTable);
        }
    }

    public ChartSeriesType ChartSeriesType
    {
        get { return _chartType; }
        set
        {
            _chartType = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ChartSeriesType);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The correct way to register the `ChartType DependencyProperty` is:

```
// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ChartType.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChartTypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ChartType", typeof(ChartSeriesType), typeof(AgilityChart), new UIPropertyMetadata(ChartSeriesType.Bar
            , new PropertyChangedCallback(dataChanged)));

    private static void dataChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("data changed");
    }
```

Now, the `dataChanged()` method is being called.

Comment: I don't quite fallow where are you using this property in your code. As I see it you can add to one chart many series each with different type and char type is doing nothing.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't actually want to post the `AddSeries` method stuff to this question, it is not doing anything right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One mistake I see in your code is that you add `dataChaged()` call to your property setter. This setter is only a convenience for you. It wont be called by binding. To react to dependency property change set callback delegate in `UIPropertyMetadata` that you pass while registering dp.

Moreover first argument of `UIPropertyMetadata` constructor is default value of property and `ChartSeriesType` looks like an enum so null in not appropriate default.

Next thing is that the dp owner type is set to `AgilityChart` and should be `SampleChart`, because that is your class name.

Comment: Yikes! I'm still a bit of a newbie at WPF so bear with me. The mistake that was causing me to think it wasn't functioning correctly was not setting the `PropertyChangedCallback`. Thanks for the help!